# Getting chosen file type from SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog

In the SaveFileDialog with WinForms, I provide the option to save an Excel file or csv file. How can I get the option selected?

```
SaveFileDialog exportDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
exportDialog.Filter = "Excel spreadsheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Comma-separated values file (*.csv)|*.csv";

if (exportDialog.Filter.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // do something based on chosen file type
}
```

Comment: You forgot . with csv type.

Comment: `if (Path.GetExtension(exportDialog.FileName).Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) DoSomething();`?

Comment: Note that `exportDialog.Filter.ShowDialog()` won't compile. I believe you meant to use `exportDialog.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get file extension from Save file dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990910/how-to-get-file-extension-from-save-file-dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `FilterIndex` of `SaveFileDialog` like this:

```
SaveFileDialog exportDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
exportDialog.Filter = "Excel spreadsheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Comma-separated values file (*.csv)|*.csv";

 
            if (exportDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (exportDialog.FilterIndex == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Excel");
                }

                if (exportDialog.FilterIndex == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CSV");
                }
            }
```

**Note: Index of items will start from 1.**

Comment: Note that it's not really a good idea to rely on `FilterIndex`. The user may select the XLSX filter from the dropdown but still (accidentally or intentionally) type a filename with a CSV extension. Also, you might have something like `"All Supported Files|*.xlsx;*.csv|..."` in your filter. In which case, `FilterIndex` won't be really useful.

Comment: I completely agree. But question was about `how to get the selected option` not about `file extension`